# Promises with ES6 destructuring fails when one of the promises don't succeed

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

There are a tons of topics about it but I couldn't find this case. Let me explain:

```
const [call1, call2, call3] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
```

If they succeed it should return allright, yes? But what if it fails? It throws me this: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): (intermediate value) is not iterable

I could make it `const calls = await.Promise.all(promises)` then use it like `calls[0]` but is it possible any other way?

Comment: I want to also add that I don't want to use .then just because it makes my code nested. I have a lot of requests under my function and want to make them look clean so I didn't want to go nested.

Comment: what do you want to do when one of them fails?

Comment: @EmelCD I am already doing that, check the sample code please. I want to destructure them

Comment: @RameshReddy I want to get the error message then I will be handling the error

Comment: If one of your promise fail, It mean it throws an error. I would wrap this code in a `try { ... } catch (e ) {  ... }` block and handle the error from there.

Comment: @OzanMudul use try and catch blocks

Comment: Let's say I have 5 API calls, would it watch any exception thrown from the promises? Can I do it something like ``Promises.all(promises).catch`` then return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awaiting a promise that will reject will cause the function to throw an exception. You handle that with a `try-catch`.

```
try {
  const [call1, call2, call3] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
} catch (error) {
  // Assuming the rejection value is an Error instance.
  const message = error.message
}
```

Comment: Well after all, I have to wrap all my promises in one try catch block. Thanks for the answer mate!

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand how `Promise.all` works.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):
The `Promise.all()` method takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of the input's promises have resolved, or if the input iterable contains no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error.

Example:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(1)
const promise2 = Promise.reject('dummy error')
const promise3 = Promise.resolve(3)

const promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3] 

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(values => ...)
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

> Output: 'dummy error'

Instead, you might consider `Promise.allSettled`.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled):
The `Promise.allSettled()` method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

The same example, but with `Promise.allSettled`:

```
Promise.allSettled(promises)  
.then(values => console.log(values))
```

> Output: [
> { status: "fulfilled", value: 1 },
> { status: "rejected", value: 'dummy error' },
> {  { status: "fulfilled", value: 3 }
> ]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like I need to write more lines :)))))))) no shortcuts :/

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled),
this returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises
have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

So even if any of the promises reject, allSettled will resolve and will give you details of each promise outcome.

Browser compatibility is here:
[allSettled compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled#browser_compatibility)

```js
async function testAllSettled() {
    const promises = [1,2,3].map(n => new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout(n % 2 ? res: rej, 100, n)));
    let result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    console.log('Promise.allSettled result:', result);
}

testAllSettled()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: We don't use ES11 currently. Will try other solutions but thanks for your answer!